# I can't change place of my keyboard on screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to change my keyboard on screen place but I dont know how to do anyone know it? code is :

```
def click(key):
    if key == "<-":
        entry2 = entry.get()
        pos = entry2.find("")
        pos2 = entry2[pos:]
        entry.delete(pos2, tk.END)
    elif key == " Space ":
        entry.insert(tk.END, ' ')
    else:
        entry.insert(tk.END,key)
button_list = [
'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','<-',
'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'
,' Space '
]
r = 2
c = 0
for b in button_list:
    rel = 'groove'
    command = lambda x=b: click(x)
    if b != " Space ":
        tk.Button(pencere, text = b, width = 5, relief = rel, command = command).grid(row = r, column = c)
    if b == " Space ":
        tk.Button(pencere, text = b, width = 30, relief = rel, command = command).grid(row = 10, columnspan = 10)
    c+=1
    if c > 10 and r == 2:
        c = 0
        r+=1
    if c > 8 and r == 3:
        c = 0
        r+=1


mainloop()
```

if anyone want I can send full code but I think you dont need more

Comment: I don't know what you mean.   Nothing in this code places the keyboard on the screen.  This places buttons inside a window called `pencere`.  Do you know how to move `pencere`?

Comment: pencere = Tk() but I tried change it place doesnt work ):

Comment: Are you aware of the `geometry` method on the root window?

Comment: Yes  I know it and using it

Comment: What did you try, exactly, and what happened?

Comment: Tim I send the full code in answers can you look again ?

Comment: 1. your code is not reproducible. 2. your question is not clear, you need to provide enough information for us to understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is about placing your window on screen.

### Solution

You can use the `geometry()` method to configure geometry of your window.
it takes a string in the format `WxH±X±Y`.

### Reference

- [Geometry strings](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/geometry.html)

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+100+100")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Billy already I know it just i want keyboard on bottom but its on top left

Comment: You never mentioned any of that details in your question, are we supposed to just assume it?

Comment: @NUrluk according to the code you posted in your "answer" (please delete this; it is not an answer; instead edit your question) you did not understand how the `geometry` function works. You can set the position in there

Comment: I dont know to what I say my problem is just keyboard on screen x or y place I cant find any code about it I want to know how I can change yeboard place?

Comment: Than how can i set the geometry for keyboard?